# COBYLA forced equality constraints using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize

I am trying to implement Constrained Optimization BY Linear Approximation (COBYLA) using scipy. What I noticed is the constraints considered need to be of `'type': 'ineq'`. My initial constraint of having a sum equal to 1, represented by `{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda W: sum(W) - 1.}` needs to be substituted with an `inequality` constraint. Is there a way I could force such a change in the `lambda`?

Comment: Use `1 <= x <= 1`

Comment: Adding to above comment: while potentially introducing numerical-trouble, this is imho the only approach you can take here and it's also done in [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/#cobyla-constrained-optimization-by-linear-approximations).